# How to update a specific div with ajax and jquery

Tags: html, css, ajax, jquery

I'm working on site and it has a fram. think of the gmail frame. And much like the gmail app I want only the inner div to be updated when clicking links on the navbar. I've got it so the div changes, but it certainly does not give me the results I'm hoping for. this is a rough outline of what I have

```
<div id=container>
   <div id=page>
      ... some child divs in here
   </div></div>
```

Because the container has a fixed scroll bar I don't want it to change I want to only replace the page div. this is what I managed to come up with on the jquery side. I'm just a beginner so I don't really know what I'm doing but I'm trying to learn.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img src='bin/pics/loading.gif' alt='loading…' width='32px' height='32px' style='top: 250px; left: 250px;' />";
    var loadUrl = "bin/ajax/load.html";
    $("#mybuton").click(function(){
        $("#page").load(loadUrl);
        location.hash = 'ajax';
    });
});
```

the load html contains this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bin/main.css" />
<div id="page">
    <div id="child">
        <h1> sometitle </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What results are you getting? Is the contents of your load.html file inserted at all? Do you expect that stylesheet to do anything in the body of your document?

Comment: yeah i get something, but the css isn't working properly and I'm not sure if i should create new id's for the html being inserted. Like "#pageajax" or something. but yeah my main issue is not knowing how to style what i insert or what divs are being replace and what divs aren't. I pretty much know the basics of how this stuff works but i'm not sure on anything.

Comment: (If I understand correctly) Personally I would avoid dynamically loading a stylesheet like that. I'm not sure all browsers will obey. It's more conventional to hard-code all possible styles on the page, in one or more stylesheets, then do any restyling by switching classNames and/or `.style...` / `.css(...)`.

Comment: ah, alright thanks, i'll try and do that. that makes more sense. I really wasn't sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Jquery ajax link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Eg Code :

```
ajax_control = jQuery.ajax({
    url: "target.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {variable_name: variable_value}
});
ajax_control.always(function(){
    $('#content').html(ajax_control.responseText);
});
```

By assigning the call to a variable ("ajax_control" in the above example), you can abort whenever you want, by using :

```
ajax_control.abort();
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to answer with links, nor just text, so here is an example of how can you make a div/table or mostly any html container to change it's content.

**If you're using MVC with Razor it'd look like this**

`TestView.cshtml`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Test",
                       "TestController", 
                       new AjaxOptions {
                           HttpMethod = "GET",
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                           UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" }))
{
    Search User by ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table id="searchResults">
</table>
```

`TestController.cs`

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult Test(int id)
    {
        var model = myDbContext.Users.Single(q => q.UserID == id);

        return PartialView("_PartialViewTest", model);
    }
}
```

`_PartialViewTest.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.User>

<table id="searchResults">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach(var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Email</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**...and if you want to do it using classic ASP.NET, it'd be like this:**

`TestPage.aspx`

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <button type="button" onclick='testCall()'>Test!</button>
            <hr />
            <div id="ajaxResult">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

`Scripts.js / TestPage.aspx`

```
function testCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "TestHandler.ashx",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: callbackTestCall
    });
};

function callbackTestCall(payload) {
    document.getElementById("ajaxResult").innerHTML = payload;
};
```

`TestHandler.ashx`

```
public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Random random = new Random();

        string actualData = random.Next(2001).ToString();

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";

        context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(actualData));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // Whether or not the instance can be used for another request
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

If you need further information please, let me know.

Comment: the code I wrote will work for asp.net c#, but you can adapt it to the language you're using, I tried to provide you a clean/easy way to update a div. Which language are you using?

Comment: i use jquery and php. i've never done anything with asp.net or c#. i was looking through your code and as complete and detailed as it looks (thank you) i didn't really understand what was going on