# Spring MVC + AJAX content update

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC, but to be honest I'm learning it. I'd like to know (tutorials, links, anything much appreciated!) what's the best way to do content update, ie of a div using AJAX. First thing that I'm trying to do is simple calculator which uses 2 values, after pressing a button I'd like to show a div with a result. Sample code

```
<form th:method="post" action=""
        class="form-horizontal" id="bmiForm">
        <div class="control-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('height')} ? error">
            <label class="control-label" th:text="#{bmi.height}" />
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="height" type="number" min="0" th:field="*{height}" /> <span class="help-inline" th:errors="*{height}">[error]</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('weight')} ? error">
            <label class="control-label" th:text="#{bmi.weight}" />
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="weight" type="number" min="0"  th:field="*{weight}" /> <span class="help-inline" th:errors="*{weight}">[error]</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="data" th:fragment="bmiResult">
            // I'd like this content to be hidden at beginning and display the result, after handling by a controller.
            <span id="randomid" type="text" th:text="${user.bmi}" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" id="calculateBmi" name="_eventId_calculateBmi" class="btn btn-primary" th:text="#{calculate}" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically use the html() function to update a div when a specific function finishes.
But then again there is other ways to update using ajax depending on what your requirements are such as append. You can focus on individual elements or refresh whole pages.

Personally i target individual divs for simplicity and efficiency.

here is a example [How to update a specific div with ajax and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116273/how-to-update-a-specific-div-with-ajax-and-jquery)

Simple example

```
<html>
//random html code
<div id="calculator_result">Result</div>

<a href="javascript;:" onClick="calculateResult()">Click Me</a>
</html>

//ajax functions
<script>
function calculateResult() {
$("#calculator_result").html("23");
}
</script>
```

The above example should place 23 into the div with id calculator_result.

Hope that helps. If you need more please let me know and ill assist you.

Comment: Next question is how to handle it by controller - as a get method with parameter? Tried something like this, but I've got following error: "Ambiguous mapping found", because two methods was defined for the same path.

Comment: There are a lot of ways, easiest way is with RestController annotation. That way you make a the functions within restcontroller same way you would with normal controller, all RestController does is the conversion to/from JSON. Heaps of documentation and examples on it on google. If you struggle post a question (as it is off topic now) and i'll get you more data.

Comment: I use thymeleaf and it's specific tags so could I have prepared div, which just needs the result and with param hidden="true" and then after ajax call just make some nice transition and change the hidden param to false?